# How to reject a message

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue, worker

I am implementing a client/workers system using ActiveMQ and I would like to implement a manual Message Acknowledgement and Message Rejection.

Why reject messages? If a worker has too many tasks coming at it, I want that worker to tell the broker to re-queue the original message.

I know there are ways to auto acknowledge or implement transactions, but I'd rather have something like this:

1. Messages need to be acknowledged within 5 seconds
2. If they are not acknowledged, the broker will send the message to a different worker
3. Works can manually reject a message at any time

How can I implement this (without just resending the message to the broker manually)

UPDATE:

To rephrase the question slightly:
**How can I ensure unacknowledged messages are re-added back to the queue (and re-delivery can go back to the same consumer that previously did not acknowledge it even -- say that consumer went offline and then came back)**

Comment: if there was a method like "message.reject()" that would automatically handle all this, that would be perfect actually!

Answer (score 3):

ActiveMQ web page about queues:

> If a consumer receives a message and does not acknowledge it before
>   closing then the message will be redelivered to another consumer.

That's what you want, right? So you have to turn off the AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT mode and use another mode: CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE or probably more selective the INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE.

Rejecting a message is not (yet) possible, see [ActiveMQ-Docu](http://activemq.apache.org/should-i-use-transactions.html):

> There is no JMS 'unacknowledge'.

Comment: By "closing" do they mean call a close function in the Listener class?  If so, which one? Also is there a timing aspect here. I.e., if a message isn't acknowledged within 5 seconds of delivery, assume it did not get delivered?

Comment: By "closing" they mean "closing the consumer". This is a way for the worker to say "I cannot handle messages now, I'm too busy". Exactly 5 seconds will be difficult, but you could give the 'maxInactivityDuration' a try. I think, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-3394 is what you want. See further discussion here : http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Acknowledgement-Timeout-td4531016.html

Comment: This actually isn't working. I switched the session to INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE and I have a map.acknowledge() call whenever I can accept data. When I can't accept data, I issue a stop command to the Consumer (and I also tried the Connection object). What happens is the worker does stop receiving messages, but ActiveMQ also empties its queue out so the messages never get delivered! I do want the messages to get redelivered by ActiveMQ even if at one point, the connection went off without acknowledgment